# Where is the Web API Controller Template?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. I have created an API application. I want to add a Web API controller class but I can't find the template for it. I am using Net Core 2.0.

Comment: Maybe this will help:
[Core 2.0 templates not listed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/119362/core-20-templates-not-listed.html)